# The mask I am creating is clipping the image I am trying to paste over it

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to paste an image(noise) on top of a background image(back_eq).
The problem is that when applying the mask (mask = np.uint8(alpha/255) the mask gets clipped [clipped mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8vOi.png)
this is the original shape i am trying to paste [the white shape should get onto the background (but black)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJj27.png)
so the result is this [clipped result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0m2ya.png)

The problem fixes when instead of normalizing with 255 we use a value smaller s.a 245 or 240 (mask = np.uint8(alpha/240))
The problem is that this is a correct normalization. Any suggestion on how to fix the mask with a correct normalization being mandatory?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

noise = cv2.imread("3_noisy.jpg")
noise = cv2.resize(noise,(300,300), interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
alpha = cv2.imread("3_alpha.jpg")
alpha = cv2.resize(alpha,(300,300), interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
back_eq = cv2.imread('Results/back_eq.jpg')

back_eq_crop = cv2.imread('Results/back_eq_crop.jpg')
im_3_tone = cv2.imread('Results/im_3_tone.jpg')

final = back_eq.copy()
back_eq_h, back_eq_w, _ = back_eq.shape
noisy_h, noisy_w,_ = noise.shape


l1 = back_eq_h//2 - noisy_h//2
l2 = back_eq_h//2 + noisy_h//2
l3 = back_eq_w//2 - noisy_w//2
l4 = back_eq_w//2 + noisy_w//2
print(alpha.shape)

# normalizing the values
mask = np.uint8(alpha/255)
# masking back_eq_crop
masked_back_eq_crop = cv2.multiply(back_eq_crop,(1-mask))
cv2.imshow('as',masked_back_eq_crop)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()



# creating the masked region
mask_to_add = cv2.multiply(im_3_tone, mask)
cv2.imshow('as',mask_to_add)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
# Combining
masked_image = cv2.add(masked_back_eq_crop, mask_to_add)
final[l1:l2, l3:l4] = masked_image
cv2.imshow('aa',masked_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(final[:, :, ::-1]);plt.axis("off");plt.title("Final Image")
plt.show()

retval=cv2.imwrite("Results/Final Image.jpg", final)
```

Comment: "this is a correct normalization" - I wouldn't say that, honestly. You're converting it to int so you're doing binary mask - but your original image is not binary, it has soft edges (antialiasing), and you're scaling it down a lot (making more grays). With /255 only pure white gets to be white, and any gray, even very light, becomes black. 255 is never a good threshold if you don't have already-binary (only pure white and pure black, no grays, no antialiasing) image. 255 *might* be a good threshold if you will play with erosion and dilation to get the edges to the shape you want them to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use binary mask threshold of 255, you have to have a properly prepared image - preferably already binary. Because ***255 means only pure white (#FFFFFF) will stay white***. Even the lightest gray will become black.

And in your case, well... the image has antialiasing (edges are softened), and you're doing scaling in the code. But **moreover, your white is not pure white. There's a hole in the result.**

**To show it, instead of just talking:**

I loaded your mask in GIMP,I loaded your mask pic in gimp, got the 'select by colour' tool, disabled antialiasing and turned threshold to 0 - everything so that only *pure* white **FFFFFF gets selected, the same as your code**.
[image]

Aaaand we see the holes. The tail is pixely already, same with hair... the hole in the face is there... Hole's colour is #FEFEFE - 254, making it black with threshold of 255.

The best threshold in such (pseudo) "black-and-white" is actually near the middle (128). Because antialiasing makes the edges be blackish-gray or whiteish-gray - no middle grays, so middle gray separates the two groups nicely. And your "visually white but not pure white" (+similar blacks) get into those groups as well. Even if you believe to have only pure black and pure white in your image - if you load it as colour or grayscale, you have 0 and 255 values anyways, so 128 will work. (I don't have access to my old code right now, but I believe I kept my thresholds around 200 when I played with images?)

***tl;dr:***

- Threshold 255 only makes #FFFFFF white, it's *never* good
- your picture has a lot of "visually white but not #FFFFFF white" pixels
- there's nothing bad in using lower threshold, even around middle of the range for pseudo black-and-white

Comment: [Btw, GIMP defaults selection's threshold (+- is applies to merge similar colour) to 15 - so it you hit pure white (255), it selects exactly what your 240 threshold does. You can play with it like that to understand it better. :)]